# Firebase Database setValue() and updateChildren() overwrites previous value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I tried to insert new data into a table in Firebase real-time database, but `setValue()` and `updateChildren()` both are overwritten previous table and value.

I know that `setValue()` is replacing previous data, but in my case, `updateChildren()` is also overwriting previous data.

In the `Firebase console`, It seems like both methods are `delete` the previous table and create a new table.

**`Firebase console` when `updateChildren()` is executed**
[image]

Is my code wrong?

**My database structure is:**

[image]

```
-accounts
    - $userId
        - missions
            - $productId
                - ...
```

and Code is:

```
val missionsReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("accounts").child(userId).child("missions")
val mission = Mission(product.id, product.imageUrl, product.title, product.logoUrl, remain.timeInMillis, "", -1, snsAddress)
missionsReference.child(product.id).setValue(mission)

val missionValue: Map<String, Any> = mission.toMap()
val missionUpdate: HashMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
missionUpdate[product.id] = missionValue
missionsReference.updateChildren(missionUpdate)
/* I also tried following methods, but it overwrites too.
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("accounts/$userId/missions/${product.id}").setValue(mission)
missionsReference.push().setValue(mission)
*/
```

Comment: what's your before and after value for accounts?

Comment: missionsReference.child(product.id).updateChildren(missionUpdate)  change last line to this and check again

Comment: can post firebase database structure screenshot here? it will helpful to understand easily.

Comment: @NileshPanchal I updated screenshot of Firebase console :)

Comment: @JinsonPaul Sorry, it's still overwrite previous data X(

Comment: @user1872384 I updated [Screenshot of Firebase console when updateChildren() is executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4Pnj.png). I hope it to be a reference to you :)

Comment: I think from the above images you are trying to update the node misson , for updateChildren to work you need to point the database reference to mission/"0", and the HashMap should contain only the child values(like "comment,"imageUrl" etc)

Comment: The value of HashMap is the issue I think,, HashMap should only contain the child values and make the last line like this missionsReference.child(product.id).updateChildren(missionUpdate)

Comment: @JinsonPaul I tried `missionsReference.child(product.id).updateChildren(missionValue)`but It still overwrites 

Comment: 안녕하세요 @David, could you please share the value of missionUpdate as well. Like what Jinson Paul predicting.

Comment: HashMap mission=new HashMap();                    
mission.put("comment","valueee");
mission.put("imageUrl","value"); ........................................................................ 
  missionsReference.child(product.id).updateChildren(mission);                                  Does not know value initilization and decleration in Kotlin this is in Java..........

Comment: @user1872384 missionValue is map and can see value [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4Pnj.png)(comment, imageUrl, etc.), and missionUpdate is map with one child like [ productId : missionValue ]. in that screenshot, missionUpdate is [ 0 : { "comment": "@fake_instagram", "imageUrl": "" ... }]

Comment: Does not understand why the value 4 is appearing instead of 0 if you want to update the child of mission,, if you want to update instead of 4 it should be 0.. If you want to add another field just add push() before updateChildren

Comment: @JinsonPaul `mission.toMap()` method is initialize mission HashMap :) the `missionValue` is the HashMap what you think :-)

Comment: you need to add 0 to the reference. val missionsReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("accounts").child(userId).child("missions").child(0)

Comment: @user1872384  , i too think HashMap should only contain the individual child values and database refrerence should be pointed to mission/0

Comment: @user1872384 I tried `...child("missions").push()` and `...child("missions").child(product.id).updateChildren(missionValue)` but both are still overwrites  and missionUpdate HashMap is reffering to [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) :)

Comment: if you don't want to specify/hardcode 0 you can use push instead of updateChildren

Comment: @David Have you solved the issue?

Comment: @user1872384 I already tried `push()`, but it just make random name table and not help for overwrite issue.

Comment: @AlexMamo nope, I still trying to solve issue 

Comment: @David Ok, I'll write you an answer in short time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I gave up create missions array in account table. and I tried like, and it works.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("missions").child(id).setValue(mission)
```

Still I don't know why this method is works and previous methods are not works. In my opinion, it looks like problem of database level(or depth?)

[Screenshot of Firebase console. it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHBrs.png)

Answer (score 2):

Seeing your database structure and assuming you have to achieve this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- accounts
         |
         --- userId
               |
               --- missions
                     |
                     --- 0
                     |   |
                     |   --- //Mission details
                     |
                     --- 4
                         |
                         --- //Mission details
```

Please use the following lines of code:

```
val missionsReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("accounts").child(userId).child("missions")
val mission = Mission(product.id, product.imageUrl, product.title, product.logoUrl, remain.timeInMillis, "", -1, snsAddress)
missionsReference.child("4").setValue(mission)
```

But instead of passing a hardcoded value to the `child()` function, I recommend you using the random key are generated by the `push()` function like this:

```
missionsReference.push().setValue(mission)
```

Now, your database structure will look like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- accounts
         |
         --- userId
               |
               --- missions
                     |
                     --- randomId
                     |   |
                     |   --- //Mission details
                     |
                     --- randomId
                         |
                         --- //Mission details
```

Thre is no need to use `updateChildren()` function in this case. This function is used to update properties under a `Mission` object, for exmaple if you want to change the `imageUrl`` property.

Comment: Hi David! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: I'm sorry for the late confirmation. I've tried both methods (hard-coded child value and push()), but still overwrites the previous mission table X^(

Comment: There is no way to override a node using my code above. Please edit your question by adding your changed code.

Comment: I also think the above code will not overwrite the data. I still do not know what's wrong, but the same problem arises when I use your code as it is 

Comment: Please edit your question by adding your changed code to see where the problem is.